# WPF logarithimic chart

Tags: wpf, charts

I have some data that I want to present on the chart. the data is as follows:

- Item1 -> value: 100
- Item2 -> value: 5
- Item3 -> value: 1000
- Item4 -> value: 200
- Item5 -> value: 350
- Item6 -> value: 600
- Item7 -> value: 30

For the presentation I want to use logarithmic chart (in order to see small and large values). How can I do this in WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the visifire trial edition and do it easily ... [CHART DESIGNER](http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_wpf_charts_gauges_designer.php)

Comment: no I cannot, I want to use charting component from .NET framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you solved your problem with the charting component in .NET 4.0 (it is relatively simple control so you may need to look at another offering -- be it commercial or open source).

Mindscape WPF Elements contains a lot of [chart controls for WPF](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/wpfelements/wpf-charting) and does support logarithmic scale on the axis.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot use third-party libraries